# Templates parametrized for enums

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I want to do this:

```
template <enum Type>
class Message {
private:
     Type m_type
};

enum StdInMessages { PrintHello, Echo, ... };
class StdInMsg : Message<StdInMessages>
{ ... }

enum NetworkMessages { DoSomethingElse, Shutdown ... };
class NetworkMsg : Message<NetworkMessages>
{ ... }
```

Of course, the actual messages are slightly different

Why doesn't this work?

```
template <enum T> class ATemplate {};
```

I get this error

```
error: use of enum ‘T’ without previous declaration
```

Comment: Well, is the enum `T` declared before?

Comment: do you meant `class NetworkMsg : Message<NetworkMessages>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not valid syntax for a template **unless what you're looking for is what Konrad answered**.

You need to either use `typename` or `class`.

The following should do it:

```
enum X
{
   a
};

template <typename T> class ATemplate {};

ATemplate<X> A;
```

Comment: Ok, I had thought I saw examples where other types were used as arguments, but now I realize that those were quite different (non-type parameters)

Comment: Not really.  `template <enum E>` is perfectly valid if there is an enumeration named `E` i scope when the template is defined.  It's not very useful, however, since it results in an unnamed template argument.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, it would be instansiated using a enum value, not an enum (I think).
`ATemplate<Sunday> sunday_obj;`

vs

`ATemplate<DaysOfTheWeek> days_obj;`

Comment: @JamesKanze yes I saw Konrad's answer. I thought he wanted a template which he can specialize with an enum... I edited.

Answer (score 2):

It works if `enum T` is declared beforehand:

```
enum T {
    foo, bar
};

template <enum T> // or simply `template <T>`
class ATemplate { };

int main() {
    ATemplate<foo> x;
}
```

But judging from the variable name `T`, this isn’t what you want. Since it’s hard to guess what exactly you want, you need to be more specific.